Picked structs in rust
Is it possible to have a picked struct in such a way that the type checker doesn't have a problem with it?
Coming from TypeScript:
// Considering a main object type containing all fields:
interface User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    password: string;
};

// We can use a picked type to select only certain fields:
const get_all_users = (): Pick<User, 'id' | 'name'>[] => {/*...*/};

The Pick type makes it possible for tsc to approve of this: const picked_user: Pick<User, 'id' | 'name'> = user;
Is there any crate/language feature that I'm missing? My main point is that I don't want to explicitly name the struct, like UserPicked, which can get complicated to do when there are lots of picked variants.

No, Rust does not support the same type gymnastics that you can do in TypeScript. It doesn't even have unnamed struct types. I fail to see how the borrow-checker would be upset either way though, but you didn't include any Rust code... It makes me wonder why you would have so many picked variants such that naming them is a problem.

@kmdreko with one notable exception, a tuple, though that doesn't allow naming the fields.

Generally the way to do this is to define the smaller struct first, then embed it in a larger struct. (They will each need their own name.) The compiler certainly has no way of shrinking an existing struct type to a subset of its fields. If you can enumerate the subsets of fields you want, then this sounds like a job for an enum whose variants carry data.

I think the usual way this problem is solved is via an enum. Something like this:
enum Picked {
  User(User),
  Name(String),
  Id(String),
}

I also fail to see how this will get more complicated than having this Pick structure from Typescript.

How does this work?

Like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7c40b749cd0ab7db60a6959798fa70f3
You probably want to use references here instead of owning the value, depending on what your plan is here.
